# ddrescue gives less error without the -r option(try reading bad sectors multiple times) than with -n option(omit bad sectors)

Tags: restore, ddrescue

I have a hard drive partition (/dev/sdb1, ubuntu 16.04 partition)with bad sectors
I intend to create an image of the partition with bad sectors and then restore to a new drive/partition.

First I run ddrescue without trying to read the bad sectors using

```
sudo ddrescue -n /dev/sdb1 sdb1_n.img sdb1_n_log.txt
```

The I run ddrescue with the -r option so that repeated attempts to read bad sectors along with the good sectors:

```
sudo ddrescue -d -r3 /dev/sdb1 sdb1_d_r3.img sdb1_d_r3_log.txt
```

Strangely the second run with -r3 gives more error locations on the log file than on the first run. The size of the images are however same.

**Which image should I use for restoring the one created using -n option or the one created with -d -r3 option?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My experience is that additional sectors are read (and their content recovered) when you run the second time with the option `-r3`. So use the image *after* running with the option `-r3`.

According to the tutorial chapter *'9. A small tutorial with examples'* in

```
info ddrescue
```

I also use `-r3` (3 retries).

The **number** of areas marked as bad may increase, but the total amount of bad sectors will decrease, when new sectors are read during the `-r3` run.

In the chapter *'4. Algorithm'* we find a detailed explanation,

> The total error size is the sum of the sizes of all the bad-sector
>   blocks. It increases during the trimming and scraping phases, and may
>   decrease during the retrying phase. A sector is not marked as
>   bad-sector and considered part of a bad area until it has been tried
>   individually instead of as part of a large block read. Non-trimmed and
>   non-scraped blocks are not considered bad areas. *Note that as ddrescue
>   retries the bad-sector blocks, the good data found may divide them
>   into smaller blocks, decreasing the total error size but increasing
>   the number of bad areas.*